# DBT INIT failure

Tags: dbt

I am following a DBT course on LinkedIn and having problem in installation.
Installed it:
$ which dbt
/usr/local/bin/dbt

But when i am tring to create project or even verify installation. It is failing with following error:

```
$ which dbt
/usr/local/bin/dbt

$ dbt --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dbt", line 5, in <module>
    from dbt.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dbt.logger import GLOBAL_LOGGER as logger, log_cache_events, log_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/logger.py", line 16, in <module>
    from dbt.dataclass_schema import dbtClassMixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/dataclass_schema.py", line 13, in <module>
    from mashumaro import DataClassDictMixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mashumaro.serializer.json import DataClassJSONMixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/json.py", line 28, in <module>
    class DataClassJSONMixin(DataClassDictMixin):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/dict.py", line 21, in __init_subclass__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/dict.py", line 17, in __init_subclass__
    builder.add_to_dict()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/metaprogramming.py", line 365, in add_to_dict
    pre_serialize = self.get_declared_hook(__PRE_SERIALIZE__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/metaprogramming.py", line 203, in get_declared_hook
    if type_name(cls) != DataClassDictMixinPath:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/meta/helpers.py", line 28, in type_name
    if is_generic(t):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mashumaro/meta/helpers.py", line 54, in is_generic
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
$
```

Any help in appreciated.

Comment: Can you run the following command and respond with the output - "pip list | grep dbt".