# dbt crash after dbt init command

Tags: python, dbt

Hey I'm trying to create a dbt project but `dbt init` crashes instantly. It is the same stacktrace error as in this post:[DBT INIT failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241225/dbt-init-failure) but there is not really a solution in that project. The comment posted in that post is execute `pip list | grep dbt` =>

```
dbt                           1.0.0.34.18
dbt-core                      0.19.2
dbt-duckdb                    1.6.0
dbt-extractor                 0.4.1
dbt-mysql                     0.19.2
dbt-semantic-interfaces       0.2.2
```

I post the stacktrace here again.

```
(venv) ➜  fimetsu-dbt dbt init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/dbt", line 5, in <module>
    from dbt.main import main
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dbt.logger import GLOBAL_LOGGER as logger, log_cache_events, log_manager
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/logger.py", line 16, in <module>
    from dbt.dataclass_schema import dbtClassMixin
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbt/dataclass_schema.py", line 13, in <module>
    from mashumaro import DataClassDictMixin
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mashumaro.serializer.json import DataClassJSONMixin
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/json.py", line 28, in <module>
    class DataClassJSONMixin(DataClassDictMixin):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/dict.py", line 21, in __init_subclass__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/dict.py", line 17, in __init_subclass__
    builder.add_to_dict()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/metaprogramming.py", line 365, in add_to_dict
    pre_serialize = self.get_declared_hook(__PRE_SERIALIZE__)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/serializer/base/metaprogramming.py", line 203, in get_declared_hook
    if type_name(cls) != DataClassDictMixinPath:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/meta/helpers.py", line 28, in type_name
    if is_generic(t):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mashumaro/meta/helpers.py", line 54, in is_generic
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Before the error appeared I tried creating it but I did not install the package `dbt-mysql` and because of that I control + c out of the terminal, not sure if this is the cause. All help is appreciated.